# Searching and finding minimum in a more efficient way

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `std::vector` and am trying to do two consecutive searches as follows:

- `std::find_if()` to find elements matching with a certain condition
- `std::min_element()` to obtain the minimum of them

Here is a snippet of code I'm trying:

```cpp
class Node{
public:
Node(int a, bool b)
    : num(a),
      is_true(b){
}
int num;
bool is_true;
};

int main(){

vector<Node> List;
List.emplace_back(1, false);
List.emplace_back(2, true);
List.emplace_back(40, true);
List.emplace_back(10, true);

vector<Node>::iterator itr = find_if(List.begin(), List.end(), [&](const Node node){
    return node.is_true;
});

auto comparator = [](Node a, Node b){
    return a.num < b.num;
}

Node minNode = std::min_element(itr, List.end(), comparator);
cout << minNode.num << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This results in displaying `1`.

I'm sure that I'm not supplying the arguments correctly.

> Node minNode = std::min_element(itr, List.end(), comparator);

My question is, are consecutive searches, like pipeline, feasible using STL methods?

If so, please guide me to the correct way of using it.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: Show us the definition of Node pls.

Comment: Does this have *measurable* performance problems? If not, you really shouldn't concern yourself with it, that's just premature optimization. As one note, if you keep that list sorted from smallest to largest, you could trivially find the smallest matching value.

Comment: @tarman - I think OP expects a different number to be printed, likely 2 following their logic.

Comment: Both lambdas should take in their `Node` parameters using `const Node&` references. Also, `Node minNode = std::min_element(itr, List.end(), comparator);` shouldn't compile, as `std::min_element()` will return an `vector<Node>::iterator`, not a `Node`.

Comment: As defined here, with no expectation of sorting, you will need to filter all elements, then run the minimum pass on them after. If you can assume it's sorted, you can do it much more easily, you don't need the `min_element` pass. You're still talking *O(N)* time either way, so unless these lists are huge (e.g. millions of elements) and you're calling this frequently, like millions of times, the cost is probably inconsequential.

Comment: It's also worth noting this assumes at least one entry matches, which may not be the case.

Comment: The ranges lib may be an option `std::ranges::min(List | std::views::filter([](const Node& node){
    return node.is_true;
}), defaultVal, comparator)`...

Comment: humm the first line of the original post is gone.

I'm a C++ beginner, and a algorithm beginner as well.
This is for genuinely studying C++ purpose.

@RemyLebeau
Thank you.
Yes, the code was like this.

`Node minNode = *std::min_element(itr, List.end(), comparator)`

Thank you all for the comments.
And, yes I was expecting to see `2`, instead of `1` in the result.
But from what I read, it is not optimized implmentation in the first place.
I will rethink the optimal data structure for what I  want to achieve.